# Symfony serialized Response vs normalized JsonResponse

Tags: php, json, symfony

I'm building an API which needs to ouput some entities as JSON. I'm trying to figure out if it's better to normalize the entity and pass it to `JsonResponse` or if I should serialize it and pass it to `Response`. What is the difference between the two?

```
/**
 * Returning a Response
 */
public function getEntityAction($id)
{
    $entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->find($id);

    $json = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($entity);
    $response = new Response($json);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response
}

/**
 * Returning a JsonResponse.
 */
public function getEntityAction($id)
{
    $entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->find($id);

    $array = $this->get('serializer')->normalize($entity);
    return new JsonResponse($array);
}
```

Is there any actual difference between the two, besides the fact I don't have to manually set the `Content-Type` header for a `JsonResponse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the encoder used by the Serializer: [JsonEncode](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Encoder/JsonEncode.php#L36) with what [JsonResponse](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php#L140) does. Essentially it's the same. Under the hood both use `json_encode` to generate a string.

I guess whatever feels right for your project is a good choice. JsonResponse is mainly for convenience and as you already noted will just automatically set the correct Content Type-header and do the encoding as json for you.

Comment: You're right. I did have a look at what they do earlier, but I dug deeper. `JsonResponse` sets some [encoding options](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php#L32) which make it safe to encode HTML. It also sets the `Content-Type` header. So I think I'll use JsonEncode so I don't have to do those things myself.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about Symfony serialization, normalization is a part of serialization process in which the object is mapped to an associative array, this array is then encoded to a plain JSON object, accomplishing the serialization.

Your code using normalize function in fact can be modified to use Response class instead of JsonResponse:

```
/**
 * Returning a JsonResponse.
 */
public function getEntityAction($id)
{
    $entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->find($id);

    $array = $this->get('serializer')->normalize($entity);
    $response = new Response(json_encode($array));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

I haven't checked the Symfony code for the serialize function, but believe part of it will be the normalize function. You can find the explain in symfony doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html
[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm aware I can do that. I'm more after what the specific differences (pros/cons) of each way of serializing the data.